# Как вызвать асинхронную функцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

**Сам код:**

```
async def get_app():
    app_info = await _bot.application_info()
    return app_info
```

При простом вызове `get_app()` я получаю генератор, если использовать `await`, то выдаёт ошибку `SyntaxError: 'await' outside function`, если делать вызов через `asyncio.run(get_app())` выдаёт ошибку `RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`.
p.s. хочу вернуть значение `app_info`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по ошибкам, Вы запускаете `get_app` из синхронного колбэка асинхронного сервера. Иначе работало либо через первый, либо черезвторой способы.

Из колбэка получить результат можно только в новый колбэк. *привет яваскрипт ;)*

```
def second_cb(fut):
    app_info = fut.result()
    продолжение кода

def server_cb(request):
    asyncio.ensure_future(get_app()).add_done_callback(second_cb)
    return
```

second_cb выполнится после завершения server_cb.

Чтоб избежать **callback-hell** перевызывай server_cb как асинхронную функцию и делай там await-ы

```
def server_cb(request):
    async def server_cb_async(request):
        r = await get_app()
        r2 = await another(r)
        # вся обработка вложенна тут...

    asyncio.ensure_future(server_cb_async(request)).add_done_callback(lambda x: pass)
```

или запустить асинхронный вариант как таск

```
    asyncio.get_running_loop().create_task(server_cb_async(request))
```

В последнее время я через таски делаю.

Как альтернативный вариант можно использовать готовую джанговскую [async-to-sync](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/#async-to-sync)

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
res = async_to_sync(get_app())
```

или

```
@async_to_sync
async def get_app(...):
```